# Something wrong in Saint Venant–Kirchhoff model?

Tags: tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics, functional-derivatives

According to the Saint Venant–Kirchhoff model, the strain-energy density function is defined as
$$
W(\boldsymbol{E})=\frac{\lambda}{2}[\rm tr(\boldsymbol{E})]^2+\mu\rm tr(\boldsymbol{E}^2)
$$
$\boldsymbol{E}$ is the Lagrangian Green strain given by
$$
\boldsymbol{E}=\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{F}^T \boldsymbol{F}-\boldsymbol{I})
$$
where $\boldsymbol{F}$ is the deformation gradient.

Consider a 2d deformation case so $\boldsymbol{F}$ is a 2x2 matrix. Clearly $\boldsymbol{E}$ is symmetric and it can be rewritten to
$$
\boldsymbol{E}=\begin{bmatrix}
e_{xx} &  e_{xy} \\
e_{xy} &  e_{yy}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, the energy density function $W(\boldsymbol{E})=\frac{\lambda}{2}(e_{xx}+e_{yy})^2+\mu(e_{xx}^2+e_{yy}^2+2e_{xy}^2)$.
So the second Piola–Kirchhoff stress $\boldsymbol{S}$ is
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{S}&=\frac{\partial W}{\partial \boldsymbol{E}}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial e_{xx}} & \frac{\partial W}{\partial e_{xy}} \\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial e_{xy}} & \frac{\partial W}{\partial e_{yy}}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda(e_{xx}+e_{yy})+2\mu e_{xx} & 4\mu e_{xy} \\
4\mu e_{xy} & \lambda(e_{xx}+e_{yy})+2\mu e_{yy}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\neq\lambda\rm tr(\boldsymbol{E})\boldsymbol{I}+2\mu\boldsymbol{E}
\end{align}
We derive a contradiction with $\boldsymbol{S}=\lambda\rm tr(\boldsymbol{E})\boldsymbol{I}+2\mu\boldsymbol{E}$ !
Am I going wrong here?

Comment: Note that the bottom left element of the derivative matrix should read $\frac{\partial W}{\partial e_{yx}}$ rather than $\frac{\partial W}{\partial e_{xy}}$, which provides the resolution as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\E{{\bf E}}
\def\J{{\bf J}}$Consider a scalar-valued function of an unstructured matrix, $W(\E)$.
Using the denominator layout we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial W(\E)}{\partial\E} 
&= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
W_{11}&W_{12} \\
W_{21}&W_{22}
\end{array}\right],
\end{align*}
where $W_{ij} = \partial W/\partial e_{ij}$.
A first pass at interpreting the derivative when $\E$ is symmetric is
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial W(\E)}{\partial\E} 
&= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
W_{11}&W_{12} \\
0&W_{22}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
It is natural to expect this derivative to be symmetric.
Unfortunately, it is not the case.
The correct thing to do is to symmetrize,
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial W(\E)}{\partial\E} \right)_{\mathrm{sym}} 
&= \frac12
\left(
\frac{\partial W(\E)}{\partial\E}+
\left(\frac{\partial W(\E)}{\partial\E}\right)^T\right) \\
&= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
W_{11}&\frac12 W_{12} \\
\frac12 W_{12}&W_{22}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
With this definition of the derivative of a scalar-valued function of a symmetric matrix, the claimed result can be verified.
This seemingly ad-hoc procedure can be justified.
See [Srinivasan and Panda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06491v2), for example.
(Thanks to @greg for pointing out this paper in a comment to [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4106230/26872) to a related question.)

Amusingly, this result can be found by the following manipulation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial W(\E)}{\partial\E} 
&= \frac{\partial W(e_{11},e_{12},e_{22})}{\partial\E} \\
&= \frac{\partial W(e_{11},\frac12(e_{12}+e_{21}),e_{22})}{\partial\E} \\
&=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
W_{11}&\frac12 W_{12} \\
\frac12 W_{12}&W_{22}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
Note that
$e_{12} = x e_{12}+(1-x)e_{12} = x e_{12}+(1-x)e_{21}$.
The "most symmetric" combination of $e_{12}$ and $e_{21}$ occurs for $x=1/2$.